# What is the limit of a Kalashtar's communication with its Quori in dreams and visions?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, eberron

I know that the Quori and the human part can never fully communicate, but what is the limit of such communicaiton? Would for example, an orphan Kalashtar be able to discover or be given the name of its Quori spirit by the Quori itself?

Would it be able to guide him to a specific place or time? A face/person? A certain quest?

From reading the lore, it doesn't seem like that's what usually happens and it's quite subtle, but I do wonder if it's possible at least in case of perhaps a stronger than usual connection, perhaps in the case of an aberrant mind sorcerer.

Comment: Do not answer in comments. Do not argue about "answering in comments" in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this is a question a DM needs to decide on, but whatever you come up with should follow the idea that the quori connection is primarily subconscious.

It's entirely possible an orphan might learn the name of their quori without knowing what it means, just a strange word that echoes in their dreams and feels personal and important. They probably will never understand what's happening to them without a mentor, though it's just possible they could piece together enough information from their dreams and outside sources to figure out an outline of their true nature.

In terms of sources for this, while the main *Rising From the Last War* book doesn't give much guidance, there's a section on Orphan Kalashtar in *Exploring Eberron*, which is available on the DM's guild. It's a third party supplement written by Keith Baker, the original author and designer of the Eberron setting, so it's pretty much as solid as an unofficial book can be in terms of lore (or at least his version of it; the book's foreword is clear that it's only "what I would do").

It comments that an orphan's quori spirit tries to communicate through "dream-visions and instincts", but without context, orphans rarely understand their quori bond. However, those instincts drive them towards the light, and orphan kalashtar that lean darker will tend to have deep inner conflicts as they fight against those drives.

Comment: I would caution against taking Keith Baker’s solo work so seriously—he doesn’t have sole control over Eberron, he works with a team that includes other writers and numerous editors, and does not have final say. Moreover, like many creators, his work when he has no one looking over his shoulder is... not the same quality as the final product that goes through other editors.

Comment: For what it's worth, *Exploring Eberron* does credit three designers in addition to Keith, as well as an editor and a passel of playtesters, so it's not exactly Keith writing screeds in his garage.  Still, you make a good point and I'll edit to make it sound less like I'm saying this is official.

Comment: Oh sure, I’m sure this is higher-quality than his blog—which is my point of comparison and so probably not totally fair—but ultimately it matters when no one can tell a creator “no.”

Comment: Thank you the amazing answer. I'll look up the book you mentioned. Considering the lack of source material, even these are welcome. :D